# What is known about functions with alternating signs of partial deriavites?

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request

Lately I have come accross a class of functions with alternating signs of their partial derivatives, in detail the class looks as follows
$$\Big\{f:\mathbb{R}^n\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}: (-1)^k \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{i_1}\cdots\partial x_{i_k}}f \geq 0,\ k=1,...,n,\ i_j\in\{1,...,n\},\ j=1,...,k\}\Big\}$$
it is particularly interesting in mathematical economics. Anyways, there seems to be not much literature on these functions and I am wondering what the properties of this class of functions are. Can anyone recommend any literature or papers on this matter?